AWS Cognito with Apache Superset on Docker: "Error Invalid login. Please try again"
I'm trying to integrate AWS Cognito with Superset.
Superset is running on a Docker.
Prior to implementing Cognito, everything was loading just fine - superset is working.
On my page https://momo.com/login/ I click on "login with cognito" button and I'm redirected to the AWS domain for the login. There I input my credentials, followed by 2FA, and after successfully doing that instad of being redirected to the superset dashboards, I'm sent back to the login page https://momo.com/login/ with the error "Invalid login. Please try again."
When I check the logs, I see the following:
2024-12-01 19:41:02,182 - WARNING - Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped
2024-12-01 19:41:51,768 - ERROR - Error returning OAuth user info:

I've tried implementing A LOT of different logging, but they didn't return anything so i removed them for clarity here. The errors and warning above is the best i got.

I've downgraded the "wekzeug" tool to another version to see if there's any improvemets - nothing.
I think the issue might be with the code logic somewhere.
I'm pretty sure the Cognito configuration in AWS is set properly

Here's my superset_config.py:
# Superset Configuration
RATELIMIT_STORAGE_URI = 'redis://redis:9999/0'
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PROTO = 'https'

# Import necessary modules
import os
import json
import logging
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH  # Import AUTH_OAUTH directly from flask_appbuilder
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth  # Import Authlib for OAuth
from flask import request, redirect, url_for, session
from jose import jwt  # Import jwt for decoding the token
import time  # For checking expiration

# Set up logging
log_dir = '/log/my_logs'
log_file = os.path.join(log_dir, 'my_debug.log')

# Enable OAuth authentication
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

# Define Cognito's OAuth provider details
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [{
    'name': 'cognito',
    'token_key': 'access_token',  # OAuth token key
    'icon': 'fa-cogs',
    'remote_app': {
        'client_id': '111',
        'client_secret': 'xxx',  # Replace with actual client secret
        'base_url': 'https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_123456',
        'request_token_url': None,  # Cognito does not require this
        'access_token_url': 'https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',  # Cognito token URL
        'authorize_url': 'https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize',  # Cognito login URL
        'access_token_method': 'POST',
        'api_base_url': 'https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com',  # Cognito IDP base URL
    }
}]

# Configure the callback URL for OAuth
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = "https://momo.com/oauth-authorized/cognito"

# OAuth Token Exchange Logic with scopes
def exchange_oauth_code_for_token(code, state):
    """Exchange the OAuth code for tokens, with scopes."""
    app = appbuilder.get_app()  # Initialize the app instance
    oauth = OAuth(app)
    
    cognito = oauth.register(
        'cognito',
        client_id='111',
        client_secret='xxx',  # Replace with actual client secret
        authorize_url='https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize',
        access_token_url='https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',
        access_token_method='POST',
        api_base_url='https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com',
    )
    
    try:
        # Exchange the code for the access token and ID token, with scopes
        scopes = ['openid', 'email', 'profile']
        
        # Exchange the code for the access token and ID token, with scopes
        token = cognito.fetch_access_token(
            code=code,
            redirect_uri=OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
            scope=' '.join(scopes)  # Pass scopes as a space-separated string
        )
        
        return token
    except Exception as e:
        return None

# OAuth Callback Logic
def oauth_authorized_callback():
    """ Handle the OAuth callback from Cognito. """
    code = request.args.get('code')
    state = request.args.get('state')

    if not code:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))  # Redirect if no code is found

    # Exchange the authorization code for tokens
    token = exchange_oauth_code_for_token(code, state)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))  # Redirect if token exchange fails

    # Store the tokens in the session for future use
    session['access_token'] = token['access_token']
    session['id_token'] = token['id_token']

    # Check if the access token is valid
    if not check_token_validity():
        return redirect(url_for('login'))  # Redirect if token is invalid

    # Fetch user info from Cognito using the access token
    oauth = OAuth(appbuilder.get_app())  # Reinitialize OAuth instance
    cognito = oauth.register(
        'cognito',
        client_id='111',
        client_secret='xxx',  # Replace with actual client secret
        api_base_url='https://momo1.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com',
    )

    try:
        user_info_response = cognito.get('https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_123456/userinfo', token=session['access_token'])
        user_info = user_info_response.json()  # Parse the response to get user data

        # Optionally store user info for further use
        session['user_info'] = user_info

        # Ensure the user is registered in Superset (using email as unique identifier)
        if user_info:
            user = appbuilder.sm.find_user(email=user_info.get('email'))
            if not user:
                user = appbuilder.sm.add_user(
                    username=user_info.get('email'),
                    first_name=user_info.get('name'),
                    last_name=user_info.get('name'),
                    email=user_info.get('email'),
                    role=appbuilder.sm.find_role("Admin")  # Or use any default role
                )
    except Exception as e:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))  # Redirect if user info fetch fails

    # Redirect to the appropriate authenticated page (Superset Dashboard)
    return redirect("https://momo.com/superset/dashboard/dashboard_1/")

# Additional settings for OAuth
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"  


